# Connect to a database with an HTML form and obtain data for making tables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database, getjson

I have the following "connect.php" file to connect to the database:

```
<?php
 
    // establishing DB connection
  
   if(isset($_POST['button']))
   {
    $text=$_POST['Database'];
    
   }
   
    $host = "host=localhost";
    $port = "port=5432";
    $dbname = "dbname=$text";
    $dbuser = "user=postgres";
    $dbpwd = "password=********";
    
 
    // connection string    
 
    $dbconn = pg_connect("$host $port $dbname $dbuser $dbpwd");
 
    // validating DB connection
    
     
 
  if (!$dbconn)
   {
        echo 'Connessione fallita';
 
    }  
    
 
?>
```

an html form to fill in the $dbname field of the previous script:

```
<html>
<body> 
<form action="page.html"  method="post" target="_blank">
  <label for="Database">Database:</label>
  <input type="text" id="Database" name="Database"><br><br> 
  <input type="submit" name="button"    value="Submit">
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

The page HTML where to view the table:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">   
    
 <script src="js1.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="table1" class="table">    
    <table  >
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Field1</th>
          <th>Field2</th>         
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody id="result">
      </tbody>
</table>
</div> 
   </body>
</html>
```

the js1.js script to generate the tables:

```
$(function() {
      $.getJSON("script.php", function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, row) {
          $("#result").append("<tr>");
          
          var $tr = $("<tr>");
           
          $.each(row, function(index2, column) {
            $tr.append("<td>" + column + "</td>");
          });

          $("#result").append($tr);
           
        });
      });
    });
```

And The script.php to get data:

```
<?php
 // establishing
 include('connect.php');


  $query = 'SELECT... FROM...';
    
    
    $result = pg_query($query) or die('Error message: ' . pg_last_error());

    
    while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $records[]=$row;
    }

    foreach( $records as $record )      
        $json[] = array($record['Name'], floatval($record['TempoMedio']) );


  header("Content-Type: application/json");
  echo json_encode($json);
   
?>
```

I believe there are problems with the script to generate tables, as nothing is displayed.
While if instead of using the form, I write the database name directly on the "connect.php" file, everything works correctly.

how can I view the data on the table by connecting via the form?

Answer (score 0):

The POST request to `page.html` is a **different** HTTP request to the GET request to `script.php`.

You aren't sending a database name to `script.php` (which I assume includes `connect.php`) but only to `page.html` (which is an HTML document and not a PHP script so, unless there are some unusual server configuration settings in play, the POST data will be ignored).